# Opening web.config file causes Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate to hang and crash

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

**Situation:**  
I installed Visual Studio 2012 on top of my previous Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I uninstalled VS2012 shortly thereafter along with all SQL 2012 database junk and yadda yadda. Everything in VS 2010 seems to be good, but when I try to open my web.config file VS hangs indefinitely.

**Tried:**

(1) Downloading and replacing the dsref80.dll that gets overridden by VS2012

(2) Uninstalled all VS extensions, including NuGet

(3) Created new website and web.config file. Problem persists

**Question:** Does anyone have any other ideas about what could cause the web.config file to cause VS2010 to hang and crash after clicking on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. For some reason the web.config file was set to open with source code editor by default and not the HTML editor. 
For anyone else who runs into this issue, the answer is simple.

> Right-click the web.config file ---> Open with ----> Highlight HTML Editor ---> Set as Default.

**Update (Dec, 2013):** Although I was able to access the web.config file using the method mentioned above, I later realized that it was more of a Band-Aid than a solution. Using the html editor causes a lot of validation warnings and renders intelliSense useless. The correct solution is to run the repair option from the Visual Studio 2010 install DVD, that fixes everything.

Comment: Any new thoughts on this? I'm having the same problem on VS 2015 but the HTML Editor is definitely a downgrade.

Comment: I can only speak from my own experience, and I have none with VS 2015. That being said, my web.config file was corrupted. Running the repair option from the install DVD repaired it. Have you tried that?

Comment: No I haven't. But you make me wonder if there are errors in certain web.config files that are crashing inconsistently.

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you. I know I did a bit of research in an attempt to salvage my web.config file. In the end I went with the repair option, so I assume nothing else worked for me. Bear in mind this was years ago. If memory serves, no files were harmed by the repair operation. Sorry I can't be more helpful on this.

Comment: @AndrewRalon What was the default editor? For me the default was the JSON editor (possibly because the file is named `web.config` not `web.xml`) ... I've changed the default editor for this file, from the JSON editor to the XML editor (not the HTML editor), and am now keeping my fingers crossed (i.e. hoping that it won't crash again).

Comment: @ChrisW I believe it was the JSON editor. Did switching the default editor to the XML editor work?